# Deleting messages from people no longer interested in item

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketplace

I have items with many replies (what are they called? messages, threads, ???) most of which are dead ends (people not interested, too far away, changed mind, etc.)

How do I "cull the dead wood" replies?

Lots of message help says to hover over the Gear and click Delete. No such option is available in Marketplace replies.

NOTE: There doesn't appear to be any way to flag them which would help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

On desktop it has the gear to delete the messages right by the sellers name.

On mobile hold down on name and menu pops up, press delete.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Open Marketplace message thread on your phone. Press down the person chat you want to delete. A red delete icon will pop up. Press *Delete*.